# How to access a field from a Model when calling it's parent

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am creating a basic cms/wiki as a learning project. Please forgive my noobish questions.

My wiki has pages. There are different types of pages. They have some fields in common and some unique fields. 
I've included three of my models to demonstrate how I've undertakes this. (one model with the common fields that the actual pages inherit from)

```
class DefaultPage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    edited_date =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)
    child_pages = models.ManyToManyField("self",blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,editable=False,blank=True)
    def __unicode__ (self): 
        return self.title
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(DefaultPage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Page(DefaultPage):
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)

class LearningObject(DefaultPage):
    archivefile = models.FileField(upload_to='static/learningobject/archivefiles/%Y/%m/%d')
    indexpath = models.CharField(max_length=254,editable=False)
    def unpackarchive(self):
        archive = self.archivefile
        filename = os.path.basename(str(archive))

        folder = str(filename).split(".")[0]
        print folder
        index_found = "False"
        with zipfile.ZipFile(archive,"r") as z:
            for each in z.namelist():
                if each == "index.html" or each == "index.htm":
                    index_found = "True"
                else:
                    pass
            if not index_found:
                print "zip file does not contain a valid index.html file"
            else:
                path = os.path.join("static","learningobject","unpackedarchives",folder)
                z.extractall(path)
                self.findindex(path)
    def findindex(self,path):

        print path
        for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'index.ht*'):
                print filename
                self.indexpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
        print self.indexpath

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.unpackarchive()
        super(LearningObject, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My urls.py passes the defaultpage.slug to

```
url(r'^(?P<default_page_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.defaultpageview, name='defaultpageview'),
```

a view that DefaultPage.objects.get(slug=default_page_slug)

```
def defaultpageview(request, default_page_slug):
context_dict = {}
try:
    default_page = DefaultPage.objects.get(slug=default_page_slug)
    context_dict['default_page'] = default_page

except:
    pass
return render(request,'wiki/default_page.html',context_dict)
```

which in turn ends up in a template

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{default_page.title}}</title>
    </head>

    <body>
       <h1>{{default_page.title}}</h1>
       {% if default_page.body %}
       <p>
        {{default_page.body}}
        <p>
          {%elif default_page.indexpath %}
          {{default_page.indexpath}}
          {% endif  %}




    </body>
</html>
```

However I am unable to call default_page.indexpath or default_page.body

Am I able to use the method I am attempting or do I need to pass all Models across in the view rather than the parent?

Sorry if the terms I've used are not correct. Please feel free to edit to correct me.

Comment: Make sure you know how class inheritance works in Python.  Models are normal normal Python classes. Also read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Comment: Thanks. The answer is halfway down the page. If you have a Page that is also a DefaultPage, you can get from the DefaultPage object to the Page object by using the lower-case version of the model name:

Answer (score 0):

You're quering for DefaultPage objects, so that's what you get. A DefaultPage object doesn't have any of those fields; only the subclasses do. If you want to use `body`, you'll need to query for the class that contains that field, and the same for `indexpath`.

Comment: Ok. So after 5 mins of thought I'm thinking that in my view I'll need to include a bunch of if statements to pass the correct subclass in the context_dict and pass it to different template pages depending on subclass.

Comment: Yeah, it's not pretty. My advice is usually to avoid model subclassing altogether.

Comment: Actually @allcaps had the answer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance  about halfway down. Rather than default_page.indexpath you just need to call default_page.learningobject.indexpath to get the subclass